# Runtime crash while using _tcsset

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

**1.** I wrote the following code which compiles but crashes at run-time showing "Access violation writing" while calling **_tcsset** .

```
void function(TCHAR *tsatz)
{
    printf( "Before: %s\n", tsatz );
    _tcsset(tsatz,'*');
    printf( "After: %s\n", tsatz );
}

void main( void )
{
    TCHAR* tsatz;
    tsatz = new char[256];
    tsatz = "This is a test string ";
    function(tsatz);
    getchar();
}
```

Where am I wrong while using _tcsset ?

**2.**  I know all the "**safe**" functions work if we tell them how big the target buffer is. But if i need to use _tcsset_s in "function" where tsatz is coming from external, is there a way?

I am a beginner. Any help i could get is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're modifying a string literal (and leaking memory at the same time). Try `TCHAR tsatz[] = "This is a test string ";`.

Comment: Thanks @user657267 , it worked. It would really be helpfull if you could help me with 2nd part of the question. As far as my understanding goes, i wont be able to use _tcsset_s in my case. Please tell me whether i am right or wrong.

Comment: If you are a beginner, you shouldn't really use `TCHAR` and all the `_t*` shit. It was designed as an interface helper when moving code from Windows 95 or earlier and not  really useful anymore. For example, your code will only work if `TCHAR` is `char`, so you could just as well *use*  `char`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @BoPersson. I will try to keep it simple in my future implementations.

Comment: Additionally, if you use VS2010 to learn C++, you miss out on the revised C++11 and C++ 14 standards. Using VS2015 would be a much better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying a string literal, this is undefined behavior.

```
tsatz = "This is a test string ";
```

This will not copy the string literal into `tsatz`, it simply assigns `tsatz` to point to the address of `"This is a test string ";`, which **cannot be modified**.
One way around this is to declare `tsatz` as an array and initialize it with the string literal, which will automatically copy the text into the array for you

```
TCHAR tsatz[] = "This is a test string ";
```

If you need to keep track of the size of an array, you will either need to do so explicitly (note that `sizeof` an array will only work if the operand actually is an array, and not a pointer):

```
void function(TCHAR *tsatz, size_t numberOfElements)
{
    _tprintf( "Before: %s\n", tsatz );
    _tcsset_s(tsatz, numberOfElements, '*');
    _tprintf( "After: %s\n", tsatz );
}

void main( void )
{
    TCHAR tsatz[] = "This is a test string ";
    function(tsatz, sizeof tsatz / sizeof(TCHAR));
    getchar();
}
```

or use a template

```
template<size_t sz>
void function(TCHAR (tsatz&)[sz])
{
    _tprintf( "Before: %s\n", tsatz );
    _tcsset_s(tsatz, sizeof tsatz / sizeof(TCHAR), '*');
    _tprintf( "After: %s\n", tsatz );
}
```

Or you could just use `std::basic_string` instead.

Comment: Thanks @user657267, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you assign a read-only C string to the pointer variable `TCHAR* tsatz;`; hence the access violation.

POSSIBLE SOLUTION:

```
TCHAR tsatz[256] = "This is a test string ";
function(tsatz);
```

"_tcsset()" and friends are non-portable; you're not likely to see them very often even in Windows-only code.

A much better solution, if possible for your application, would be to use C++ "std:string".

For example,

```
std::string tsatz = "This is a test string ";
std::fill(tsatz.begin(), tsatz.end(), '*');
```

Comment: @ user657267  - Thank you for the correction.  I meant "std::fill()", and I updated the post accordingly.  The main point I was trying to make is that using TCHAR, and especially using _tcsset(), is probably a Bad Idea unless this is legacy code with a lot of other modules that use TCHAR extensively...